How to get the box-counting dimension of a fractal given by an array?
Question
Let's say we have an array that via ArrayPlot gives us an approximate plot of a fractal. E.g. the Mandelbrot set:
array = Table[Length[NestWhileList[#^2 + x + y * I &, 0, Abs[#] < 2 &, 1, 10]],
    {y, -1.5, 1.5, 0.01}, {x, -2, 1, 0.01}];
ArrayPlot[array]


How could I get the Minkowski-Bouligand Dimension (via box-counting)?
Why I'd like to do this: I've been interested in fractals for a while and more recently I've been interested in plotting and animating via Mathematica and as I was playing around with ArrayPlot it occurred to me that if you look at the boundary of the fractal / represents the set, then $D \approx \tfrac{\ln\left( N\left( \varepsilon \right) \right)}{\ln\left( 1 / \varepsilon \right)}$ with $\varepsilon$ as the side length (step size) and $N\left( \varepsilon \right)$ as the number of boxes (at boundary of the fraktal) would be the approximate dimension for small enough $\varepsilon$. But when I try to calculate this via Mathematica I have some problems.
If you want some example fractals and their dimension: see List of fractals by Hausdorff dimension (note: that these are the values for the Hausdorff dimension but that's the same as the box counting dimension for most of them or more general $\dim_{\text{Hausdorff}} \leq \dim_{\text{box-counting}}$)

My work and ideas
As described above, the approximate dimension would be given by $D \approx \tfrac{\ln\left( N\left( \varepsilon \right) \right)}{\ln\left( 1 / \varepsilon \right)}$ for small enough $\varepsilon$. More precisely, $D = \lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0^{+}} \tfrac{\ln\left( N\left( \varepsilon \right) \right)}{\ln\left( 1 / \varepsilon \right)}$ (but I don't think Mathematica can calculate that via the method aka I would try the evaluate the approximated one). The first thing we should do is get the array into an appropriate shape (so that we can work with it). Assuming we manage to ensure that all the elements at the boundary of the set are clearly distinguishable from the others, we could count them and that would be our $N$ and our $\varepsilon$, which we know from generating the array, so the information should are sufficient. After some work I cam up with:
MinkowskiBouligandDimension[arr_, stepsize_, 
   OptionsPattern[{Option -> "All"}]] := 
  Module[{Dim}, 
   Dim[newarr_] := Log[Count[Flatten[newarr], 1]] / Log[1 / stepsize]; 
   Piecewise[{{Dim[arr], 
      OptionValue["Option"] == "All"}, {Module[{Boundary}, 
       Boundary[newarr_] := 
        Quiet[Table[
          If[And[Part[newarr, a - 1, b] === Part[newarr, a, b] === 
             Part[newarr, a + 1, b], 
            Part[newarr, a, b - 1] === Part[newarr, a, b] === 
             Part[newarr, a, b + 1]], 0, Part[newarr, a, b]], {a, 1, 
           Length[newarr]}, {b, 1, Length[Part[newarr, 1]]}]]; 
       Dim[Boundary[arr]]], OptionValue["Option"] == "Boundary"}}]];

Dim calculates the dimension by counting the number of $1$ in the array and using the formula above. Boundary gives as output an array which changes all values ​​of the input array that have the same values ​​in the area to "0" and otherwise returns "1" as long as only the boundary remains. Boundary does not work that well but it seem fine enough (the last plot is the ArrayPlot of Table[If[Abs[NestWhile[#^2 + x + y * I &, 0, Abs[#] < 2 &, 1, 10]] < 2, 1, 0], {y, -1.5, 1.5, 0.005}, {x, -2, 1, 0.005}]):

Calculation:
array = Table[
   If[Abs[NestWhile[#^2 + x + y * I &, 0, Abs[#] < 2 &, 1, 10]] < 2, 1, 
    0], {y, -1.5, 1.5, 0.005}, {x, -2, 0.5, 0.005}];
MinkowskiBouligandDimension[array, 0.005, Option -> "Boundary"] (* 1.45129  *)

But that answer is quite of... It should be $\approx 2$ and not $\approx 1.45129$. The error seems to grow for higher step-sizes which should be not the case aka there is some error in the code or the method wrong (Increasing the iterations makes something better but the problem seems to persist.).
I tried the same for the Julia set of $z^{2} + i$ (with step size $0.005$: $\approx 1.75577$ (it should be $\approx 1.2$)), the Sierpinski carpet (with step size $3^{-7}$ and $7$ iterations: $\approx 1.84682$ (it should be $\log_{3}\left( 8 \right) \approx 1.8928$ aka this is quite good)) and a few more fractals and it seems to work for some of them (e.g. the sierpinski carpet).

Maybe the issue is that you need really small boxes in order to get a good approximation of the fractal dimension. Consider pts = JuliaSetPoints[0.25, "ClosenessTolerance" -> 0.001]; Log@Length[pts]/Log[1/0.001] which is kind of like doing a ball packing estimation as mentioned on the Wikipedia page. As also mentioned on Wikipedia, the fractal dimension should be about 1.08. The code gives 1.39. Replacing 0.001 by 0.00001, which takes a while to compute, we get 1.27. Unfortunately, decreasing further (by magnitudes) will take even more time, but I'm wondering if that is what it takes.

If you want to plot the edge of M set, try this link , and also a p5js example by me. Click right top </> to see the source code.

First, let's properly write your boundary filtering function to avoid the index error you're encountering, which currently requires the use of Quiet. To achieve this, we can use a common technique in image processing: expand the matrix (or image) by padding the edges with replicated values from the original boundary, to help maintain consistent filtering behavior near the edges.
BoundaryFilter[arr_] := Module[{paddedArr, rows, cols},
    {rows, cols} = Dimensions @ arr;
    paddedArr = ArrayPad[arr, 1, "Fixed"];
    Table[
            If[
                And[
                    Equal[Part[paddedArr, i - 1, j],
                        paddedArr[[i, j]],
                        Part[paddedArr, i + 1, j]
                    ],
                    Equal[Part[paddedArr, i, j - 1],
                        paddedArr[[i, j]],
                        Part[paddedArr, i, j + 1]
                    ]
                ],
                0,
                Part[arr, i - 1, j - 1]
            ],
            {i, 2, rows + 1},
            {j, 2, cols + 1}
        ]
   ];

Next, as an illustrative example, let’s test the BoundaryFilter function with a small matrix of the Mandelbrot fractal, using a matrix element highlighting function to observe it clearly:
array1 = 
Table[If[Abs[NestWhile[#^2 + x + y*I &, 0, Abs[#] < 2 &, 1, 10]] > 2, 0, 1], 
{y, -1.5, 1.5, 0.5}, {x, -2, 0.5, 0.5}];

EdgeHighlightedMatrix[mat_?MatrixQ, twoColors_ : {Blue, Red}] := 
  Module[
    {min, max, rules, interiorElements, borderElements, hborderRules, 
    hinteriorRules},
    {min, max} = If[
            SquareMatrixQ[mat],
            MinMax @ Range @ Length @ mat,
            MinMax[Dimensions[mat] - 1]
        ];
    rules = Flatten[
            MapApply[Thread @* Rule,
                Thread[{Array[{##} &, Dimensions @ mat], mat}]
            ]
        ];
    interiorElements = If[
            SquareMatrixQ[mat],
            Cases[rules,
            Rule[{i_, j_}, elem_] /; 1 < i <= max - 1 && 1 < j <= max - 1
            ],
            Cases[rules,
            Rule[{i_, j_}, elem_] /; 1 < i <= max && 1 < j <= min
            ]
        ];
    borderElements = Complement[rules, interiorElements];
    hborderRules = 
    MapAt[Style[#, Part[twoColors, 1]] &, borderElements, {All, 2}];
    hinteriorRules = 
    MapAt[Style[#, Part[twoColors, 2]] &, 
     interiorElements, {All, 2}];
    ReplacePart[mat, Join @@ {hborderRules, hinteriorRules}]
   ];

Grid[{{"Original", "Extended", "Filtered"}, 
{MatrixForm[Map[Style[#, Red] &, array1, {-1}]], 
 MatrixForm[EdgeHighlightedMatrix@ArrayPad[array1, 1, "Fixed"]], 
 MatrixForm[Map[Style[#, Darker@Green] &, BoundaryFilter[array1], {-1}]]}}, 
 Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> {0.5, 0.5}]


To approach the problem of fractal dimension through box counting, I highly recommend a post by Mark McClure titled Box counting method for fractal dimension, published as an answer on Mathematics Stack Exchange. Below, I provide the BoxCounting function of the idea McClure presents in his post:
BoxCounting[array_?MatrixQ] := Module[
    {test, count, radii, counts, logRadii, logCounts, fit, 
    fractalDimension},
    test[matrix_] := Boole @ Greater[Length @ Cases[matrix, 1, {2}, 1], 0];
    count[n_] := Total @ Flatten @ BlockMap[test, array, {n, n}];
    radii = Table[2 ^ k,{k, 0, Floor @ Log2 @ Min @ Dimensions @ array}];
    counts = Table[count @ r, {r, radii}];
    logRadii = Log[1 / radii];
    logCounts = Log @ counts;
    fit = Fit[Transpose[{logRadii[[2 ;; -3]], logCounts[[2 ;; -3]]}],
          {1, \[FormalX]}, \[FormalX]];
    fractalDimension = Coefficient[fit, \[FormalX]];
    fractalDimension
    ];
(*Since your matrix is ​​already binarized, some of McClure's code is omitted.*)

Finally, I’ll include a couple of examples using BoxCounting to determine the fractal dimension, both without boundary filtering and with boundary filtering:
array2f = BoundaryFilter[array2];

GraphicsGrid[{{
 Column[{Style["Fractal dimension" <> " " <> ToString[BoxCounting[array2]], 12], 
         ArrayPlot[array2, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 420}]}], 
 Column[{Style["Fractal dimension" <> " " <> ToString[BoxCounting[array2f]], 12], 
     ArrayPlot[BoundaryFilter[array2], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 420}]}]}}, 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 500}]


Using McClure's box-counting code provides an effective estimation of fractal dimension in the first case, where no boundary filtering is applied, and the fractal dimension approaches 2, which aligns with the expectation for a filled or "area-like" structure in a 2D space. In the second case, with boundary filtering applied, the fractal dimension approaches 1, consistent with the topological dimension of a curve. This is because the boundary filtering emphasizes the structure's edges, transforming it into a shape more similar to a one-dimensional line. For an accurate result that reflects the Mandelbrot set’s full complexity, higher resolution and a filled structure approach are essential, as these capture more of the fractal's detail.
Note 1:
As @corey979 insightfully noted, “the boundary of the Mandelbrot set has a Hausdorff dimension of 2, so getting 1 as the box-counting dimension greatly underestimates the correct value.” This highlights that increasing refinement level is crucial. Thanks again, @corey979, for this valuable reminder!
Note 2:
The behavior observed with the calculation of the Minkowski-Bouligand dimension is quite interesting and expected based on how fractal dimensions are defined and computed. When constructing array2f for the Mandelbrot set with a step size of 0.005, you create a matrix that captures the complexity of the fractal, allowing for good resolution of the set's boundary. When using a step size greater than 0.005, you effectively group more pixels together, which reduces the captured details and often leads to a dimension approximation closer to 2, treating the set as more "filled" or "area-like." Conversely, using a step size smaller than 0.005 tends to lose fine boundary details, causing the dimension to approach 1, emphasizing the structure of the boundary as a one-dimensional line. This behavior illustrates how the choice of step size affects the estimation of the fractal dimension. For instance, the result of MinkowskiBouligandDimension[array2f, 0.02] yields approximately 1.96557, showcasing the delicate balance between resolution and dimension approximation in fractal analysis.
I hope you find my response helpful, as it builds upon McClure's work.

Just a note: the boundary of the Mandelbrot set has a Hausdorff dimension of 2, so getting 1 as the box counting dimension greatly underestimates the correct value.

Thanks for pointing this out, @corey979, I've added your observation!
